# About Fivetran custom connectors

Tags: sap-erp, fivetran

[Introduction]
I want to connect SAP ECC ERP (old version of S/4HANA) with Fivetran.
Fivetran's data source connector is compatible with S/4HANA and ByDesign for SAP products,
I couldn't find a connector for SAP ECC ERP (Old version of S/4HANA).

【Question】
For sources that don't have connectors like SAP ECC ERP, do we need to use Function connectors and develop our own connectors?
■ Reference articles
https://fivetran.com/docs/functions

In addition, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if you have any other countermeasures for products that do not have connectors.

Thank you.